# Nested Select Statement Query with error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP' "

Tags: mysql, sql

I have been through a few other posts relating to my error, but none of the solutions seem to work. I'm fairly new to SQL so sorry if its something really simple. I have two tables

1. Movie Inventory - which has columns movie_title, onhand_qty, and replacement_price
2. NotFlix - which has subscriber_name, queue_nbr, and movie_title

I am trying to join the two tables to output the total replacement price cost per customer, but when I do it gives me the error titled above. Here is my code, thanks in advance for any help!

```
SELECT subscriber_name, SUM (replacement_price) as replacement

FROM

(SELECT NotFlix.subscriber_name, NotFlix.movie_title, NotFlix.queue_nbr, MovieInventory.replacement_price

FROM NotFlix 

INNER JOIN MovieInventory

ON NotFlix.movie_title = MovieInventory.movie_title
)

GROUP BY subscriber_name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an alias:

```
SELECT AliasNameHere.subscriber_name, SUM (AliasNameHere.replacement_price) as replacement

FROM

(SELECT NotFlix.subscriber_name as subscriber_name, NotFlix.movie_title, NotFlix.queue_nbr, MovieInventory.replacement_price as replacement_price

FROM NotFlix 

INNER JOIN MovieInventory

ON NotFlix.movie_title = MovieInventory.movie_title
) AliasNameHere

GROUP BY subscriber_name;
```

Comment: It worked as soon as I put the alias in there. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

I Just don't get why are you doing a temporary table in FROM clause, you could just do a basic INNER JOIN here and potientialy avoid problem with alias name :

```
SELECT NotFlix.subscriber_name, SUM (MovieInventory.replacement_price) as replacement

FROM NotFlix 

INNER JOIN MovieInventory

ON NotFlix.movie_title = MovieInventory.movie_title

GROUP BY subscriber_name;
```